# How to use script tag in template engine ejs?

Tags: javascript, api, server, ejs

When you make web page with `html`, `css`, `js`, you can connect it in the format below for `js` in the html file.
What should you do in for ejs?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ratailerPage.js"></script>
```

I put the `js` file in the public folder, and the server file declared it as public static.
The `css` in the public file is connected well, but only the `js` is not working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/retailerPage.css">
```

Comment: Open network tab and see if it's loading

Comment: Check in your Network tab, if you can see the javascript file. Also check if it isn't a typo. I see to different names. "ratailerPage" and "retailerPage"

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem. My browser gave me an error:

```
caught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "ejs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I had the "public" folder set to static in the server file. The path to the js file was also set correctly in ejs with respect to the static folder.

The only thing that helped me was **reinstalling** all the packages in node_modules. I typed into the console:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

and

```
npm install
```